# Home page shows index of/ when shared on facebook

Tags: wordpress

I use seo yoast for pages and posts. so they are displayed properly with proper images and description on facebook. but Seo yoast doesnt not provide customization of homepage(recentposts). When i post my website http://www.liftupideas.com on facebook. it shows **index of/** istead of any description and image. i searched about it but could find any working solution most of the posts are outdated about it.

**I need to know how to show proper title ,description and Image**

Answer (score 0):

Your open graph tags seems to be correct, try clicking the 'fetch new scrape information button' in the [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you this problem was solved by doing this by me. am sharing this may be it will work for others.

I made a new page with (default settings) named it blog and adding that title and description seo yoast of that blog page.

Then i went on Settings> Reading and selected
Front page displays> static front page>about page
Recent posts> Blog(my newly created page with seo yoast meta description and title)

then i saved the setting. and after few mins i set back
Front page displays> recent posts

And after now my problem is solved. i see the same layout as i wanted on facebook.

Ref: Personal Experience

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is very late to this topic but one of our clients experienced the same issue this week, and I offer this for anyone else who might come across this problem.

The issue turned out to be that the company that manages their DNS had made a change that directed all IPv6 traffic (for the particular domain in question) to a server directory listing page, which has the title "Index of/".

As we are now aware, the Facebook scraper prioritises IPv6 over IPv4 and so the "Index of/" page was being scraped by Facebook. You can check this for yourself by running the domain name through the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and seeing what IP address is returned. You can also scroll further down and click the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" link to see mark-up of the page Facebook is actually scraping.

Anyhoo, once we realised this they fixed the routing issue and the the problem was solved.